# global name 'reverse' is not defined

Tags: python, django, paypal, django-paypal

I'm using the `django-paypal` library to use PayPal payments on my site.

Following the [example](https://django-paypal.readthedocs.org/en/stable/standard/ipn.html), I have set the `paypal_dict` and added the form.

```
paypal_dict = {
        "business": settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
        "amount": "10000000.00",
        "item_name": "name of the item",
        "invoice": "unique-invoice-id",
        "notify_url": "https://www.example.com" + reverse('paypal-ipn'),
        "return_url": "https://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
        "cancel_return": "https://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",

    }
```

However, I am getting the error `global name 'reverse' is not defined` I am using Python 2.7.9, what's going on?

Comment: You want to reverse the string?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what it's trying to accomplish, that came straight from the example and trying to use it raises the error.

Comment: There is no builtin function named `reverse`. Did you define one somewhere? Or expect to have imported one?

Comment: Where's the traceback? The offensive code?

Comment: Presumably this is supposed to be the Django `reverse` function, which you get for free if your module is loaded as a Django view, but not if you import or run it in some other way.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to import the function `reverse`:

For [Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) and up:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

For older [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

It's specific to django, but it looks like you're trying to build a URL anyway, so it's probably what you want.

Answer (score 7):

in Django2.0 :

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

--Use this code in `models.py`......

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('url-name', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` isn't a builtin function in python. Presumably, it's a function in some web framework for doing reverse-routing (getting a url path from a name). The `notify_url` has to be a url in your application that Paypal will send notices to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no builtin function `reverse` in Python. (There is a `reversed`, but I doubt it's what you want.)

There *is* a [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/) function in Django. But you only get Django builtins in code that's loaded as a Django view or similar; if you import or run this code in some other way, it won't exist.

So, presumably, you've gotten something wrong earlier in the instructions, and aren't actually creating a view. (The Django-PayPal instructions are clearly written for someone who's already an experienced Django developer; if you don't understand basic Django concepts you will probably need to work through [the tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/intro) first.)

Answer (score 1):

The url for paypal-ipn is probably defined in django-paypal's urls. I guess that importing django's reverse will solve this problem.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this solution to "reverse not defined" problem, and I still had this mistake... I imported reverse in all my urls files, with no effect... Then I imported reverse into views.py files and my local server started to work... 
The original solution to this message is right, but author didn't mention where to post import reverse, so I thought may be I will complete the original answer... If somehow I am wrong, I apologize, but it worked for me...

Comment: Your answer must be formatted to understand. like problem and then solution. thanks